# Can not save the changes made in a datatable

Tags: jsf

So I have the following table:

```
                    <h:dataTable id="shoppingCartTable" value="#{cartBean.shoppingCartList}" var="shoppingCartItem" width="100%" >



                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                          <h:outputText value="Item" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:commandLink value="#{shoppingCartItem.name}">

                        </h:commandLink><br/>


                      </h:column>


                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                          <h:outputText value="Quantity" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:inputText id="quantity" value="#{shoppingCartItem.quantity}" size = "2" /><br/>
                     </h:column>

             </h:dataTable>
```

With the following commandButton

```
            <p:commandButton
                value="Submit"
                >
                <f:ajax event="click"
                    execute="shoppingCartTable"
                    render="@all" />

                </p:commandButton>
```

Now there is a lot of other stuff on the page and all I want to do is update the Quantity values of the shopping cart items but this does not seem to be working. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do commandButton and dataTable placed inside one form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `f:ajax` with `p:commandButton` attributes:

```
<p:commandButton value="Submit" update="@all" process="shoppingCartTable"/>
```

Comment: Mmmk I tried that originally and it was not working but I did not set the process to the correct variable.